# how to maintain check boxes state across jsp pages whenever you come back on a page using javascript or jsf without storing it into database

Tags: javascript, jsf

i want my all check boxes checked whenever i come back from other pages, i want to maintain their states across pages using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking how to store state for an individual session between requests. In this case, that state is checkbox values.

You have a choice to make first: do you want to store the data on the client (in the browser) or on your server?

### Server Side

You can store this state on the server side with or without a "database" depending on how pedantic you want to be about the term.

If what you want is to avoid configuring an SQL RDBMS, you might find that the built-in storage options from most Java Servlet containers will work. In Tomcat, you can just use your Session objects as normal, but configure a "File Based Store" instead of a "JDBC Based Store." This will store session data to disk in files. Alternatively you can use StandardManager which uses in-memory storage, but does not persist session state across restarts.

Put simply, these will create a Java Map for each JSESSIONID issued by your server, and then keep the maps in memory, on disk, or in a JDBC database. For more information see: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html

### Client Side

Here you have a few options as well. The driving factor is what level of browser you wish to support. If you can tolerate restricting your users to those who use a browser with [HTML5 web storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and JavaScript enabled, things are pretty easy. If not, you can accomplish the same thing with a cookie.

The big downside to client-side storage is trust. Users (or software on their computer) can modify client-side storage. This goes for cookies, localStorage, and sessionStorage. Many developers forget this and introduce security vulnerabilities because of it. If this is for a real production web application, you'll want to wrap your state in an authenticator.

Here's a [the first](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076245/java-web-development/take-control-of-the-servlet-environment--part-1.html) in a three article series on a way to convince your servlet container to put session state into cookies in a way that is transparent to your servlets. It is missing authentication, but you can add it by following guidance such as [this bit from Rob Winch](https://spring.io/blog/2014/01/20/exploiting-encrypted-cookies-for-fun-and-profit).

### Now What?

Ok. You've decided to use client- or server-side storage for your checkbox values. Now what?

A simple (usually wrong) option is to store the checkbox input names and values in a map:

```
{"boxFoo": true,"BarBox":false}
```

The reason this is usually wrong is that it fails to distinguish which form your user was visiting. It means that if you apply this strategy to more than one form on your site, you'll have to worry about name collisions.

The next evolution is to have a structure keyed by form name and then field name. This would be a map like the following:

```
{ "formA": {"boxFoo": true,"BarBox":false},
  "formQ": {"checkAlpha":true,"BetaCheck":false } }
```

This works, but will have [annoying behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model#Writes-follows-reads_consistency) when your users use multiple tabs. You can make that behavior more predictable for your users by using per-tab identifiers -- at the expense of space in your session object -- or by using AJAX to keep the fields in sync -- which has its own perils. Or you can do what most people do an just assume that the last submitted form overwrites the state from all previous ones, tabs be damned. That's much simpler to code, but more annoying to users.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose some ways :

- send http params (in hidden field) with check boxes flags which must stay checked in each new page requested by your application . You can factorize it with a function but it stays cumbersome to do.
- store the check boxes marker flag in the http session. If the check boxes must stay checked in all the life of your user, it may be a suitable solution. Use may use a backing bean session for it as you use JSF.
  Nevertheless, store the minimum of information in it.
- store the information in a shared applicative cache to retrieve it. In this way, you stay stateless and you have not the drawback of the session if you use clustering in your servers.

There is maybe better as alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the value with a backing bean. As long as the backing bean is having the appropriate scope it will be retained on the page when you navigate to it.