# How to keep selected radio button after page refresh in a java web application

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, stripes

I am a rookie to web development  using Stripes Framework .
The web page that I am designing has 4 radio buttons .
On selection of one of the radio buttons there is a text box along with a  Submit Button visible .

When I click on the Submit button the functionality will be redirected to another jsp which has a set of values , when a value is selected , which is populated back into  the text box  which is in the jsp with the radio buttons ,but the radio button which was selected initially is being unselected .

Can you please let me know if there is a way to have the radio button selected ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to maintain check boxes state across jsp pages whenever you come back on a page using javascript or jsf without storing it into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865814/how-to-maintain-check-boxes-state-across-jsp-pages-whenever-you-come-back-on-a-p)

Comment: @Matt I do not think so .

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the selected value is there (in the request). Check it by outputting it on the jsp like ${foo}.

If so, in the jsp you should check the radio yourself like:

```
<c:if test="${foo eq 'cat'}">checked="checked"</c:if>
```

If it is not in the request may be its out of the form or so..